# Remotely check if processes are running on Windows 7 box

Tags: windows-7, remote, monitoring, tasks

I'm handling a group of applications that need to all run at the same time and work together, on around 10 machines, most of them Windows 7 pro, and a couple of ubuntu servers.

I'm trying to develop a "control center" app that would monitor running processes and warn me if one goes down or has not started normally.

On linux I can easily run ps (even remotely) and parse it, however how should I do with the windows boxes?  I looked at Tasklist, but have two problems: first for some reason I can't manage to run it remotely (working on this).

I then tried to run it locally, redirect output to file and parse this file remotely, but tasklist seems to be taking a long time to write the file, which is never consistent and causes lots of problems.

What am I doing wrong?  Is there a better way to tackle this problem?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896682

Answer (score 2):

On Windows 7 Pro and above, you can use PowerShell:

```
get-process > processes.txt
```

To output the list of processes to a text file.

Answer (score 0):

this may help to you

http://codeketchup.blogspot.sg/2012/06/how-to-check-if-specific-process-is.html

Comment: Although this may answer the question, you should give a more detailed description of the linked content and explain how it relates to the question. This will help ensure that this answer remains useful in the event the linked page is removed or goes offline. For more information, see [this Meta Stack Exchange post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259).